# How am I supposed to use wxFormBuilder Python GUI code in my applications?

Tags: python, windows, wxpython, nameerror, wxformbuilder

i'm trying to create a GUI for my Python program in Windows, and i'm kinda confused atm..

i've created the GUI using [wxFormBuilder](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxformbuilder/) and it looks like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

###########################################################################
## Python code generated with wxFormBuilder (version Jun 17 2015)
## http://www.wxformbuilder.org/
##
## PLEASE DO "NOT" EDIT THIS FILE!
###########################################################################

import wx
import wx.xrc

###########################################################################
## Class MainFrame
###########################################################################

class MainFrame ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = u"Editor_SPED_LP", pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 320,255 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.Size( 320,255 ), wx.Size( 320,255 ) )

        bSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.m_textCtrl2 = wx.TextCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer1.Add( self.m_textCtrl2, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )

        self.m_btn_abrirArq = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Abrir arquivo...", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer1.Add( self.m_btn_abrirArq, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_btn_editarTxt = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Editar .txt", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer1.Add( self.m_btn_editarTxt, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_gauge1 = wx.Gauge( self, wx.ID_ANY, 100, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.GA_HORIZONTAL )
        self.m_gauge1.SetValue( 0 ) 
        bSizer1.Add( self.m_gauge1, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_btn_ajuda = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Ajuda", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer1.Add( self.m_btn_ajuda, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_staticText2 = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.m_staticText2.Wrap( -1 )
        bSizer1.Add( self.m_staticText2, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_btn_sair = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Sair", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer1.Add( self.m_btn_sair, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )


        self.SetSizer( bSizer1 )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

        # Connect Events
        self.m_btn_abrirArq.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.abrirArquivo )
        self.m_btn_editarTxt.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.editarTxt )
        self.m_btn_ajuda.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.janelaAjuda )
        self.m_btn_sair.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.sair )

    def __del__( self ):
        pass


    # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
    def abrirArquivo( self, event ):
        event.Skip()

    def editarTxt( self, event ):
        event.Skip()

    def janelaAjuda( self, event ):
        event.Skip()

    def sair( self, event ):
        event.Skip()
```

when i run it from the terminal it doesnt show any errors...

> how am i supposed to use it with my application?

i've found this tutorial [here](http://sebastiannilsson.com/en/blogg/rapidly-building-python-gui-application/), but i couldn't understood it..

also i tried to add that code at the end of the script:

```
 if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = wx.App(False)
        frame = MainFrame()
        frame.Show()
        app.MainLoop()
```

and got this error:

```
File "gui.py", line 80, in <module>
    frame = MainFrame(seld,parent)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

so.. it looks like the gui code is fine, the problem is that i dont know how to initialize it and add some functions..

can someone help me with that, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got a sucessfull attempt using:

```
#importing wx files
import wx
#import the newly created GUI file
import gui


#inherit from the MainFrame created in wxFormBuilder and create janelaPrincipal
class janelaPrincipal(gui.MainFrame):
    #constructor
    def __init__(self,parent):
        #initialize parent class
        gui.MainFrame.__init__(self,parent)


    #what to do when each function button is clicked

    def editarTxt(self,event):
        try:
            #write the editarTxt code inside here

        except Exception:
            print 'error'


#mandatory in wx
#create an app, False stands for not deteriction stdin/stdout
#refer manual for details
app = wx.App(False)

#create an object of janelaPrincipal
frame = janelaPrincipal(None)
#show the frame
frame.Show(True)
#start the applications
app.MainLoop()
```

but i actually dont know why it worked..
still need some explanation, please.. :-)

Answer (score 4):

The issue you are having is with the "init" function/method. It accepts two arguments (self & parent) which you have to specify when creating the MainFrame object.

```
def __init__( self, parent ):
     ......
```

**self** is specified automatically (you don't explicitly specify it)

**parent** is set to None (you explicitly specify it as None)

See the screen shot below and a [wxFormBuilder - Tutorial on “A GUI for making GUIs” for Python](http://umar-yusuf.blogspot.com.ng/2015/12/wxformbuilder-tutorial-on-gui-for.html)

[image]

Comment: Where's the screenshot?

Comment: Now it's displaying. Before it was just a rectangular white box

Answer (score 4):

You just need to add the following to the bottom of your program:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame(parent=None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

What this tells Python to do is to create an instance of the `wx.App` class. The `False` parameter tells wxPython that it shouldn't redirect stdout to a new window. Next we create an instance of your class, `MainFrame` and set its parent to `None`. After that, we `Show` the frame. If we don't, the code will still work, but you won't see anything. Finally we call the application object's `MainLoop` function so that wxPython can actually start running and processing events.

Here's the full code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

###########################################################################
## Python code generated with wxFormBuilder (version Jun 17 2015)
## http://www.wxformbuilder.org/
##
## PLEASE DO "NOT" EDIT THIS FILE!
###########################################################################

import wx
import wx.xrc

###########################################################################
## Class MainFrame
###########################################################################

class MainFrame ( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = u"Editor_SPED_LP", pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 320,255 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL )

        self.SetSizeHintsSz( wx.Size( 320,255 ), wx.Size( 320,255 ) )

        bSizer1 = wx.BoxSizer( wx.VERTICAL )

        self.m_textCtrl2 = wx.TextCtrl( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer1.Add( self.m_textCtrl2, 0, wx.ALL|wx.EXPAND, 5 )

        self.m_btn_abrirArq = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Abrir arquivo...", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer1.Add( self.m_btn_abrirArq, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_btn_editarTxt = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Editar .txt", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer1.Add( self.m_btn_editarTxt, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_gauge1 = wx.Gauge( self, wx.ID_ANY, 100, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, wx.GA_HORIZONTAL )
        self.m_gauge1.SetValue( 0 )
        bSizer1.Add( self.m_gauge1, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_btn_ajuda = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Ajuda", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer1.Add( self.m_btn_ajuda, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_staticText2 = wx.StaticText( self, wx.ID_ANY, wx.EmptyString, wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        self.m_staticText2.Wrap( -1 )
        bSizer1.Add( self.m_staticText2, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )

        self.m_btn_sair = wx.Button( self, wx.ID_ANY, u"Sair", wx.DefaultPosition, wx.DefaultSize, 0 )
        bSizer1.Add( self.m_btn_sair, 0, wx.ALL, 5 )


        self.SetSizer( bSizer1 )
        self.Layout()

        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )

        # Connect Events
        self.m_btn_abrirArq.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.abrirArquivo )
        self.m_btn_editarTxt.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.editarTxt )
        self.m_btn_ajuda.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.janelaAjuda )
        self.m_btn_sair.Bind( wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.sair )

    def __del__( self ):
        pass


    # Virtual event handlers, overide them in your derived class
    def abrirArquivo( self, event ):
        event.Skip()

    def editarTxt( self, event ):
        event.Skip()

    def janelaAjuda( self, event ):
        event.Skip()

    def sair( self, event ):
        event.Skip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame(parent=None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```